# Unset a JQuery Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code setup in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JacquesKoekemoer/FzgrD/1/) so that everyone can see it. I have a piece of code that with the help of the JQuery UI library will make it into a JQuery Select.

```
 $("select").selectbox();
```

but now my question is, how do i revert to the old select ?
the reason why i want to do this is people should be able to click on one of the radio buttons and it should filter the select by that gender (the class of each option has the gender) but this doesnt work when the select has already been converted

Comment: "how do i revert to the old select ?" please explain the statement bit more

Comment: Okay so JQuery changes the <select> tags to have a div and some sub divs and lists, I want to remove the divs and sub divs reverting them back to a <select> tag, then I want to filter the options in the <select> tag, and then I want to recreate the JQuery select

Comment: Try $('select').selectbox('detach');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoud work:

```
 $('select').selectbox('detach');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a class to the the selected object instead of altering it completely, you can then always select it again quickly

Comment: What do you mean ? I don't know which of the objects in the select box  belong to which content